# TOSSIM for windows

Tags: tinyos

I am new to "Wireless Sensor Network". I need to be familiar with the simulators and emulators so I decided to use TOSSIM. So, can anyone provide with the documentation or tutorials for windows?

Comment: Have you checked official documentation - http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TOSSIM? TOSSIM itself is written in Python so OS shouldn't be a major factor assuming you got TinyOS compiler installed on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two key points that you should figure out in TOSSIM:

1. What is noise model and how to build a noise model?
2. How to run the TOSSIM simulation and how to output the log info we want?

Here are some selected docs and tutorials I have gone through before:

- Official instruction (from TinyOS wiki) of TOSSIM is essential;
- [A tutorial video from ANT Lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MAr-5DdWy8);
- [Building a Network Topology for TOSSIM (Please download and open with browser)](https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/doc/html/tutorial/usc-topologies.html)

Although TinyOS is compatible with Windows, the installation of TinyOS on Windows would be harder than that on Linux. Hope you have a pleasant WSN journey.